# Carousel effect with mouse (drag, move and release)

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a carousel of photos using the mouse (drag and stop). I've got the movement, but the photos are not centered in the frame when I release the mouse button.
I think I am close of the solution, but does not work.

Here is code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(bg='#ffffff')
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.resizable(False, False)

original_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}

def Example():

    def scroll_start1(event):
        global original_data
        global drag_data

        canvas.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)
        original_data["item"] = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        original_data["x"] = event.x
        original_data["y"] = event.y

    def scroll_move1(event):
        canvas.scan_dragto(event.x, event.y, gain=1)

    def stop_finalmove(event):
        global original_data
        global drag_data

        drag_data["item"] = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        drag_data["x"] = event.x
        drag_data["y"] = event.y

        if original_data["x"]-drag_data["x"] >0:
            #move to right
            canvas.after(1,canvas.move(1,-(760+drag_data["x"]),0))
            canvas.after(2,canvas.move(2,-(drag_data["x"]),0))
        if original_data["x"]-drag_data["x"] <0:
            #move to left
            canvas.after(1,canvas.move(1,+(760+drag_data["x"]),0))
            canvas.after(2,canvas.move(2,+(drag_data["x"]),0))
        


    canvasmaster = tk.Canvas(root, width=760, height=580, highlightbackground="white", highlightcolor="white", highlightthickness=1, background="#ffffff")
    canvasmaster.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.35, anchor="center")

    canvas = tk.Canvas(master=canvasmaster, width=732, height=570, highlightbackground="white", highlightcolor="white", highlightthickness=1, background="white")
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0 ,5000,570))
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    frame = tk.Frame(canvas, width=700, height=550, bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(20, 20, window=frame, anchor="nw", tags=1)

    imghab1foto2= customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("FILE OF PHOTO NUMBER 1"), size=(735, 520))

    fotoimghab2foto1= customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, corner_radius=0, border_width=2, border_color="#ffffff", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Roboto", size=1), text="", width=500, height=333, fg_color="#ffffff", 
        hover_color="#ffffff",  anchor="center", image=imghab1foto2, command="")
    fotoimghab2foto1.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.46, anchor="center")
    fotoimghab2foto1.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", scroll_start1)
    fotoimghab2foto1.bind("<B1-Motion>", scroll_move1)
    fotoimghab2foto1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stop_finalmove)


    frame2 = tk.Frame(canvas, width=700, height=550, bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(735, 20, window=frame2, anchor="nw")

    imghab2foto2= customtkinter.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("FILE OF PHOTO NUMBER 2"), size=(735, 520))
    
    fotoimghab2foto2= customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame2, corner_radius=0, border_width=2, border_color="#ffffff", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(family="Roboto", size=1), text="", width=500, height=333, fg_color="#ffffff", 
        hover_color="#ffffff",  anchor="center", image=imghab2foto2, command="")
    fotoimghab2foto2.place(relx=0.50, rely=0.46, anchor="center")
    fotoimghab2foto2.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", scroll_start1)
    fotoimghab2foto2.bind("<B1-Motion>", scroll_move1)
    fotoimghab2foto2.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stop_finalmove)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    Example()
    root.mainloop()
```

The effect should be to scroll through the photos continuously with the use of the mouse (press, drag and release).